# Getting $I=-I$ when doing substitutions in indefinite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

When substituting $t=\frac{1}{x}$ into $I=\int \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$, we get
$$
I=\int \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \int \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}\cdot\frac{-1}{t^2}dt = -\int \frac{dt}{1+t^2}
$$

Why does this seem to contradict the known antiderivative of $I=\arctan x+c$ and suggest $I=c$? Is there a problem with the substitution? I know how to solve the integral but I would like to understand why this happens.

Comment: In a definite integral $\int_a^{b} f(x)dx$ the variable $x$ is a dummy and you can replace it with any other variable. Not so in an indefinite integral.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget that, at the end, you must perform the inverse substitution. That is, since you began be replacing $x$ with $\frac1t$, at the end you have to replace $t$ with $\frac1x$.

Yes,$$\int\frac1{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx=\arctan(x)+c,$$for some constant $c$. What you did proves that$$\int\frac1{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx=-\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)+c',$$for some constant $c'$. Which is not amazing, since$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}):\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)=\begin{cases}\frac\pi2&\text{ if }x>0\\-\frac\pi2&\text{ if }x<0.\end{cases}$$